# How can i save/insert default value into table after if request == POST?

Tags: python, database, django, model, save

users table:

```
mysql> describe blog_users;
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| slug               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password           | varchar(300) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password_token     | varchar(300) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email              | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_verified     | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_token        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email_token_expiry | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tos                | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| active             | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_login         | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_action        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_admin           | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role               | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created            | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified           | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The form:

```
<form action="/dosave" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
    {{ user.username }}
    <label for="id_password">Password:</label>
    {{ user.password }}
    <label for="id_email">Email:</label>
    {{ user.email }}
    <input type=submit value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I can get only username, password, email from input fields. Other column value will be default value. How can I save default values for those column during saving?

model:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField()
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tos = models.BooleanField()
    active = models.BooleanField()
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
```

Comment: What is `user` in your template?

Comment: @DrTyrsa, It's a modelform, `user = UsersModelForm()`

Comment: You think Django will fill `password_token` and `role` automatically? Django is very powerful, but it can't read your mind (at least in 1.3 :-))

Comment: No, django will not fill password_token, password token will be generated in views.py. role will be default '0', that means no-role.

Comment: Why do you think `role` will be 0 by default? You should specify this explitely (see the link to docs in my answer). May be you should post your view, and tell what exacly goes wrong.

Comment: What should role be, you think?

Comment: I don't know, it's your code, not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have used a custom `user model` because Django `Users` does not have a slug field. (Please tell me if I am wrong)

Since you have created your own users table, whatever information you need to enter can be done in the view itself. In your views you can do something like this
    if request.method == 'POST':

```
    # Extract the POST values
    username = request.POST.get('username ', False) 
    .
    .
    .

    # Create new user object
    user = User()

    # Fill the POST request information
    user.username = username
    .
    .

    # Fill the default values
    user.slug = 'What ever you want'
    .
    .
    .

    # Save the object
    user.save()
```

1. First you get the data from the POST request
2. Then you create a new user object
3. Then you add the information you have received fro the POST request
4. And finally you add the default values that you want to add the default values
5. Don't forget to save in the end.

However if you want the other fields also to be displayed in your form then as has been pointed out in the other answer you can use 'fields`or '`exclude` in your model form

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email','slug')
```

and if you want to exclude a few fields and show the rest then you can use `exclude` as

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ('role',)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, its a custom model. I updated the original question/post. Check that again to understand.

Comment: Since it is a custom form you don't even need to save the default values while saving the form, in your class it self you can give a `default` attribute. for example for the filed `is_admin` you can do `is_admin= models.BooleanField(default=False)` to give a default and you can also set `editable=False` if you do not want the default value to be changed.

Comment: One more thing, when you will set default values in your class and do `syncdb` it might give an error, because syncdb can only be used for table creation. You either have to delete the table and then `syncdb` again or you can use an application like `south` that helps in schemmigration

Answer (score 2):

You should use `fields` or `exclude` in your ModelForm. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form).

If you want some fields of your model to get default values, use [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default).

Answer (score 1):

Unless Ive misunderstood the question, just set the `default` column to whatever you want the column to default to and keep the `Null` as "No"

Comment: How would i set the column to whatever i want? Would i set the column to whatever from mysql create table statement? Or, would i set the column to whatever individually from views.py? Posting example would be helpful.

Comment: You just need to set the column in the SQL database.

Comment: Sorry just edited, realised you couldnt see some of the words in my answer.